# Pop-up advertising message filling the screen

Tags: sony-xperia, ads

Sony Xperia M, model C1905.
Android 4.3 official firmware, build number 15.4.A.1.9

[image: screenshot] <sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

The blue button on the message is a link to play.google.com of "du speed booster" page. It is a useless application. All of applications on a phone installed from google play site.
First time I thought, this message is an android generated to force me to free some internal memory. Now there is enough free memory, and the message still appears.

I do not know how figure out the harmful application.
I searched in Google by words in message to find people, who faced the same message and solved the problem, but there are no such results.
I have installed the AirPush Detector, but it did not find anything.

Must I do full wipe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's not an Airpush ad. Also, these kind of ads are forbidden by the Google Playstore TOS. Always pointing to the same app *suggests* another app from the same developer placing it, not an ad module.

I'd first check which apps are running when this happens (*Settings→Apps*, select the corresponding tab). See if there are "non-essential" apps listed which you can live without. Note them down.

Second, check permissions of the apps installed. There are some [permission checker apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=194#group_379) available which make things easier for you. Fot this specific case, [Permission Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.carlocriniti.android.permission_explorer) seems to be a good candidate:

[image: Permission Explorer] [image: Permission Explorer]
<sup>*Permission Explorer:* List of permissions, apps using a certain permission (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the screenshots show, this app allows you to browse your installed apps *by permission*. Your screenshot looks like a system alert window, so the offending app most likely has the [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=perms#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission. Check for apps having this permission. Note them down.

In a third step, compare your notes: apps that were running when the message appeared, apps using the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission. If you find a match, you most likely found your offender. Uninstall it, and see whether your issue is gone then.

If this has solved your issue, don't forget the following to help others: check if that app is still on *Google Play*, and if the version there matches the version you have installed. If so, first report that app to Google, as it violates the TOS, and put a comment warning others. Google should react by removing the app from the store.